# Different dates Oracle 11g with TOAD

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, date-format, toad

I have the following queries:

```
SELECT to_date(to_char(to_date('01-FEB-1949'))) FROM DUAL;  
/*this returns 2/1/2049. */

SELECT to_date(to_char(to_date('01-FEB-1949'),'dd-MON-yyyy')) FROM DUAL; 
/*this returns 2/1/1949.*/
```

Why does the first one returns the year `2049` instead of `1949`?

By Googling I have found that I can "force" the client date format to be the one desire by changing the `key`on the registry:

```
KEY_OraClient11g_home1
NLS_DATE_FORMAT : YYYY/MM/DD
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why convert a string to a date, then to a string and back to a date again? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both functions [`TO_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions203.htm#i1003589) and [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions200.htm#i1009324) take three arguments. The two last arguments take a default value if they are unspecified.

The second argument is the format. It will default to your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter value. Since you will potentially lose information during the conversion, there is no reason to assume that the two functions are the inverse of one another.

Let's take an example with the default poor choice of format `DD-MON-RR`:

```
SQL> select to_date('01-FEB-1949', 'DD-MON-RR') d from dual;

D
------------------------------
01/02/1949

SQL> SELECT to_char(to_date('01-FEB-1949', 'DD-MON-RR'),
  2                 'DD-MON-RR') c
  3  FROM dual;

C
------------------------------
01-FEB-49

SQL> SELECT to_date(to_char(to_date('01-FEB-1949', 'DD-MON-RR'),
  2                         'DD-MON-RR'),
  3                 'DD-MON-RR') d
  4  FROM dual;

D
-----------
01/02/2049
```

This shows that we have lost data during the second step: the century was lost! The third step has to make up for it and uses the [default rule of `RR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#i116004):

> - If the specified two-digit year is 00 to 49, then
>
>   - If the last two digits of the current year are 00 to 49, then the returned year has the same first two digits as the current year.
>   - If the last two digits of the current year are 50 to 99, then the first 2 digits of the returned year are 1 greater than the first 2 digits of the current year.
> - If the specified two-digit year is 50 to 99, then
>
>   - If the last two digits of the current year are 00 to 49, then the first 2 digits of the returned year are 1 less than the first 2 digits of the current year.
>   - If the last two digits of the current year are 50 to 99, then the returned year has the same first two digits as the current year.

We're in the first case, the century chosen is the current century (20XX).

In conclusion:

- Don't rely on the session parameters for conversion because they can be changed outside of your control, use **explicit** conversion rules.
- Don't use the `RR` or `YY` format because a year has 4 digits (ever heard about the Y2K bug?)
- While we're at it, don't use the `MON` month format, your application won't work if someone uses another regional NLS setting: months use distinct abbreviations in different languages!